# Set the second tab as default tab in swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, xcode4.6.3

I am using a tab bar which has 4 tabs and I want to set the second tab as default. I wrote the following code:

```
self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 2
```

But I got the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

And one more thing can I hide a UIViewController or UITabBarController if yes then how?

Answer (score 4):

you should do it in `AppDelegate` class on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method like that

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

    if self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController != nil {
        var tabbarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
        tabbarController.selectedIndex = 2
    }
    else{
        println("couldn't reach rootViewController named UITabBarController")
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have used the above code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method but app shows first tab as default tab.

Comment: is your rootViewController named UITabBarController or different? Does it give any error?If it is not that means  self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController is nil and code block doesnt execute, you can see by writing else statement

Comment: Yes, it goes to else part. What should I do now?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I wanted to always start at tab[0] after the app had been in background. thank you

Answer (score 4):

I used Ozgur's code and updated it for Swift 3 and it works perfectly:

```
    if window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController != nil {
        let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3 // Opens the 4th Tab
    }
```

I dropped the else statement as it is pretty obvious if it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 Solution**

Inside your TabBar Controller class.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.selectedIndex = 2  // Opens the 3rd Tab
    }

}
```